# c# access an image in app_themes folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, app-themes

I have an image in my App_Themes/Default folder that I want to load into a byte array.  However I am having issues getting to the file.  Is there any easy c# way to do this?

My solution looks like this:

-Project
-App_Themes
-Default
-image1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Server.MapPath() to get the full local file path for a relative url, for example:

```
string lFileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/Default/xyz.png");
```